AWS Data Migration doesn't migrate any data
I have a DMS task to migrate full load and replication. The source is my RDS Mysql database and the target is my Open Search Domain. When I do either a full load migrate or replication, my tables are migrated but no data.  
I original was getting an error because the open search indexes didn't have a mapping. I created a mapping that matches the data types and columns of my tables, and it still will not copy any data. Any advice or anyone with experience would be appreciated.

So I figured it out yesterday. On my Open Search DMS endpoint, I had to set a setting called UseNewMapping to true. Found the answer on this article. https://dev.to/aws-builders/using-dms-to-replicate-data-from-rdsmysql-to-open-search-57cg
It appears that the dms migration task wasn’t able to create a new index mapping, and when I created it myself it wouldn’t map the data to the index mapping so it wouldn’t create the documents.
